# How to set output array into sql insert

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming that the array output like this:

```
    Array ( [0] => 'item1', 'item2'
            [1] => 'desc1', 'desc2' 
            [2] => '1', '2' 
            [3] => '1', '2' 
            )
```

And how to set the text into sql insert something like this:

```
            INSERT INTO Table (ITEM, ITEMDESC, JML) VALUES ('Item1','desc1','1','1'),('Item1','desc1','2','2')
```

In case, I like to join the $sql wit array:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Table (ITEM, ITEMDESC, JML) VALUES ";   

    Array ( [0] => 'item1', 'item2'
            [1] => 'desc1', 'desc2' 
            [2] => '1', '2' 
            [3] => '1', '2' 
            )

            INSERT INTO Table (ITEM, ITEMDESC, JML) VALUES ('Item1','desc1','1','1'),('Item1','desc1','2','2')
```

Comment: Arrays are key/value pairs. `array_combine` takes an array of keys and an array of values. Just... how would a third parameter fit in?

Comment: What you're trying to do with these 3 arrays?

Comment: ... Did you mean [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array-merge) or perhaps [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/array-merge-recursive)?

Comment: Array combine takes two parameters. First array elements is set as keys and second array elements as values. You used it here in wrong way.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: OK, I do edit the question to add jquery code to answer why need 3 array parameters.

Comment: combine array in 3 parameters please...

Comment: I need to set sql like this INSERT INTO hdetail (IDH, ITEM, ITEMDESC) VALUES ('218','i1',1,100), ('218','i2','d2',2,200)

Comment: Because I want to setup the echo $sgo into INSERT INTO hdetail (IDH, ITEM, ITEMDESC) VALUES ('223','i1','d1'), ('223','i2','d2')

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_push($destination,$value)`;

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: yes, I do that in jquery.. and trying to pass into php:

Comment: Do you have any way to setup echo $sgo into INSERT INTO hdetail (IDH, ITEM, ITEMDESC) VALUES ('223','i1','d1'), ('223','i2','d2')

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to combine 3 arrays into a main array. Then Use `array_merge` instead of `array_combine`

```
<?php

$v_tes1 = ["a","b","c"];
$v_tes2 = ["1","2","3"];
$v_tes3 = ["X","Y","Z"];
$result = array_merge($v_tes1,$v_tes2,$v_tes3);
print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: Yes, I do try something like that but the returns sql is not match, I need to set return something like this: INSERT INTO hdetail (IDH, ITEM, ITEMDESC) VALUES ('218','i1',1,100), ('218','i2','d2',2,200)

Comment: can you please provide me the arrays which you are getting from DB?

Comment: No, I'm not getting from DB for array but from form $_POST which dynamic rows like var itemnm=[]; var itemqty=[]; var itemhrg=[]; <= I want to insert, I'm just to want the echo $sgo return/print text INSERT INTO hdetail (IDH, ITEM, ITEMDESC) VALUES ('223','i1','d1'), ('223','i2','d2') <= IF 2 array_combinr has no problem, but I need 3 $isi = array_combine($v_tes1, $v_tes2, $v_tes3);
foreach($isi as $key=>$data) {
$v_tes[$key]=$key.",".$data.")";
}
$v_tes = implode(', ', $v_tes);
$sgo.=$v_tes;
echo $sgo;

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Passing in 3 parameters makes no sens at all:

array_combine accepts 2 parameters. An array of keys and an array of values.

it mpas the $values to the $keys . e.G.:

```
$keys = array('a','b');
$values = array('foo','bar');

array_combine($keys, $values);
// array('a'=>'foo', 'b'=>'bar');
```

So what exactly would adding a 3rd paramter do? Where would it go?

Comment: I was edit my question to answer why. Because the form rows are dynamic.

Comment: I was read the array_combine, yes I know but how to make 3 parameters? I dont see any ways to pass any?

Comment: But I want to set echo $sgo to INSERT INTO hdetail (IDH, ITEM, ITEMDESC) VALUES ('223','i1','d1'), ('223','i2','d2') <= 3 parameters array

Comment: is it possible to use &&